# Banish "You have forced XXX to quit" from showing on my screen again

Tags: macos, error, dialog, applications

I never want to see this popup on my computer again.

Is it possible to prevent "do not ask again" this type of dialog?

[image]

Comment: Prerelease software often has many, many bugs. Would you be able to indicate the build / version of OS X you are running in case this is reproducible on 10.9 or earlier?

Comment: This screenshot is from 10.10b2 but I see this same behavior in 10.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following, then log out and back in

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none
```

Comment: Does this affect error reporting to Apple?

Comment: @Patience If the dialog would automatically send the report to Apple, the report will still be sent. If the report is only sent if you click Report (i.e. it's a third party app) then the report will not be sent.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Apple's advice differs from what you suggest. *Help Center* content for Mavericks includes: [Report problems to Apple](https://help.apple.com/machelp/mac/10.9/help/index.html?lang=en#mh27990) with help for automatic reporting and more.

Comment: @Graham Could you expand on what you're quoting from the link? It appears to *support* what I was saying?

Comment: Clarification/discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16397024#16397024